# Monotouch - iPhone load Admob interstitials statically

Tags: ios, iphone, xamarin.ios, admob

I am trying to load Admob interstitial ads using a static class, so I can show it in a convient time.

I have created a method for loading the Interstitial:

```
public static void GetInterstitial()
    {
        interstitial = new GADInterstitial ();
        interstitial.AdUnitID = "my_ad_unit_id";

        interstitial.LoadRequest (GADRequest.Request);

        interstitial.DidReceiveAd  += (sender, args) => {
            didInterstitialLoad = true;
        } ;

        interstitial.DidFailToReceiveAd += (object sender, GADInterstitialDidFailToReceiveAdWithErrorEventArgs e) => {
            didLoadInterFailed = true;
        };

        interstitial.DidDismissScreen += (sender, e) => {
            //TODO - Handle interstitial dismiss ();
        };
    }
```

and then in my ViewController:

```
if (isInterstitialLoaded) {
            interstitial.PresentFromRootViewController(this.NavigationController);
        }
```

This works for the first time, but after that I am getting the following error in interstitial.DidFailToReceiveAd:

> Will not send request because interstitial object has been used

What can be done to fix it?

Answer (score 1):

I got this error when I tried to `interstitial.PresentFromRootViewController(this.NavigationController);`

The solution was to recreate the entire interstitial ad after dismissing the last one. So inside your `DidDismissScreen` handler, just create it again:

```
    didInterstitialLoad = false;

    interstitial = new GADInterstitial ();
    interstitial.AdUnitID = "my_ad_unit_id";

    interstitial.LoadRequest (GADRequest.Request);

    interstitial.DidReceiveAd  += (sender, args) => {
        didInterstitialLoad = true;
    };
```

HIH :)

Comment: there must be a better way no?

Comment: Probably, but it doesn't seem to have any adverse effects. At worst I imagine it creates some garbage, but then requesting a new ad must generate lots of garbage too.